# Python3 - Error when using matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm writing a code on Tests Statistics based on numbers of samples. I'm calculating Confidence Margins for different numbers of samples and so on. I've written the code to visualize Error margins as function of samples number, and now I would like to fill an area between the graphs. Unfortunately, when I call the function, I get the following error:

"*TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule "safe"*"

Here is my entire code:

```
import matplotlib
#matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math as m
from scipy.stats import t
from scipy.stats import norm
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator

# Confidence Levels
confidence_level = 0.95
# Number of Tested Samples
samples = np.linspace(2.0,20.0,19.0) # test samples
# True Mean
test_true_mean = 20.0 # krad (GomSpace TID level requirement)
# Standard Deviations
n_bins = 21
test_sigma1 = np.std(np.linspace(10.0,30.0,n_bins),ddof=1) # krad [10.0,30.0] interval
test_sigma2 = np.std(np.linspace(15.0,25.0,n_bins),ddof=1) # krad [15.0,25.0] interval
test_sigma3 = np.std(np.linspace(17.5,22.5,n_bins),ddof=1) # krad [17.5,22.5] interval
test_sigma = np.array([test_sigma1,test_sigma2,test_sigma3])
# Statistical Loop
stat_loop = 100
# Arrays creation
sim_rand_var = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size,stat_loop],object)
test_samples = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size,stat_loop],object)
test_samples_mean = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size,stat_loop],object)
test_samples_stdev = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size,stat_loop],object)
delta = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size,stat_loop],object)
error = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size,stat_loop],object)
lower_limit  = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size,stat_loop],object)
higher_limit = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size,stat_loop],object)
Ct = np.zeros(samples.size,object)
test_samples_mean_mean = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size],object)
delta_mean = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size],object)
lower_limit_mean  = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size],object)
higher_limit_mean = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size],object)
error_mean = np.zeros([test_sigma.size,samples.size],object)

#print("Standard Deviation [krad]    Test Samples (2 to 20)    Set         Error (%)")
#print("-------------------------    ----------------------    --------    ---------")

for k in range(0,test_sigma.size):
    for l in range(0,samples.size):
        for m in range(0,stat_loop):
            # Random Gaussian Numbers Generation
            sim_rand_var[k][l][m] = np.random.normal(test_true_mean,test_sigma[k],int(samples[l]))
            # Samples Mean and Standard Deviation
            test_samples_mean[k][l][m]  = np.mean(sim_rand_var[k][l][m])
            test_samples_stdev[k][l][m] = np.std(sim_rand_var[k][l][m],ddof=1)
            # Student-t Critical Values
            Ct[l] = t.ppf(confidence_level,int(samples[l])-1)
            # Deviation from the Sample Mean
            delta[k][l][m] = Ct[l]*test_samples_stdev[k][l][m]/np.sqrt(samples[l])
            # Error Lower and Higher Margins
            lower_limit[k][l][m]  = test_samples_mean[k][l][m] - delta[k][l][m]
            if lower_limit[k][l][m] < 0.0:
                lower_limit[k][l][m] = 0.0
            higher_limit[k][l][m] = test_samples_mean[k][l][m] + delta[k][l][m]
            # Test Global Error
            error[k][l][m] = 100*delta[k][l][m]/test_samples_mean[k][l][m]
            #print(error[k][l][m])
            #input = "%.3f                         %s                        %s          %.3f" % (test_sigma[k],samples[l],int(m),error[k][l][m])
            #print(input)

#print("errors_mean:")
for k in range(0,test_sigma.size):
    for l in range(0,samples.size):
        test_samples_mean_mean[k][l] = np.mean(test_samples_mean[k][l][:])
        delta_mean[k][l]             = np.mean(delta[k][l][:])
        lower_limit_mean[k][l]       = np.mean(lower_limit[k][l][:])
        higher_limit_mean[k][l]      = np.mean(higher_limit[k][l][:])
        error_mean[k][l]             = np.mean(error[k][l][:])

print(type(lower_limit_mean[0,1]))

for k in range(0,test_sigma.size):
    ax = plt.figure().gca()
    #plt.figure(k+1)
    plt.errorbar(samples,test_samples_mean_mean[k,:],yerr=delta_mean[k,:],fmt='.k')#uplims=True,lolims=True
    plt.hlines(xmin=0, xmax=25,y=test_true_mean,linewidth=2.0,color='r')
    plt.xlim(1,21)
    plt.ylim(test_true_mean-3*test_sigma[0],test_true_mean+3*test_sigma[0])
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(samples))+2)
    plt.grid(color='gray',linestyle='--',linewidth=0.5)
    plt.xlabel('Test Samples')
    plt.ylabel('Confidence Margin [krad]')
    plt.suptitle('Confidence Margins Distribution (%s%%)'%(100*confidence_level),fontsize=14)
    plt.title('Population $\\mu$ = %0.1f krad, $\\sigma$ = %0.1f krad'%(test_true_mean,test_sigma[k]),fontsize=14)

    ax = plt.figure().gca()
    plt.plot(samples,higher_limit_mean[k,:],'b',linewidth=3.0)
    plt.plot(samples,lower_limit_mean[k,:],'r',linewidth=3.0)
    plt.hlines(xmin=0, xmax=25,y=test_true_mean,linewidth=2.0,color='k')
    plt.fill_between(samples,higher_limit_mean[k,:],lower_limit_mean[k,:])#,color='g')#,alpha=.5)
    plt.xlim(1,21)
    plt.ylim(test_true_mean-3*test_sigma[0],test_true_mean+3*test_sigma[0])
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(samples))+2)
    plt.grid(color='gray',linestyle='--',linewidth=0.5)
plt.show()
```

The matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between function is called in the end of the code. I already checked the variables types, and they are all the same ().

Any good thoughts on where is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialised all your arrays to have `dtype = object`. I'm not sure why you've done this, but the `fill_between` function doesn't handle it.

The solution would be to remove the `dtype=object`. Doing this for the two arrays that you end up using in the `fill_between` should be sufficient (though I'm not sure you need object arrays at all...):

```
lower_limit_mean  = np.zeros([test_sigma.size, samples.size])
higher_limit_mean = np.zeros([test_sigma.size, samples.size])

# rest of code

plt.fill_between(samples, higher_limit_mean[k,:], lower_limit_mean[k,:])
```

One of the resulting graphs looks like:

[image]

Comment: DavidG, many thanks for that! Now the code works just fine :-). I originally added the "object" due to an error I was receiving to generate the random numbers inside the loop. I deleted it for the other arrays, and now it works.Thank you again!

Comment: @lghizoni No problem :-). "Object" arrays are rarely needed. They can be used to hold different data types e.g. a float and a string, however you lose the various advantages of using numpy arrays and may provide futher problems down the line if you try to perform any mathematical operation on the object arrays